# How to use image as subtitle in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I use the Toolbar as an ActionBar. I can set a subtitle, however is it possible to have e.g. an ImageView as a subtitle instead of text only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Toolbar` is just a `ViewGroup`,so you can define your favorite views inside it.

For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

              <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"..../>

              <ImageView 
                  android:id="@+id/imageView"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>


</<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in your code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView title = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.textView);
ImageView image = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work! But how can I get the same style of the title TextView as from the original toolbar layout?

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar behaves just like any other view. So you could into the xml definition of the toolbar, split it vertically (with weight sum) to accommodate your `ImageView` container, and place an `ImageView` there.
Then, in your Activity, you could set the image:

```
ImageView subtitleImage = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_imageview);
subtitleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_view);
```